# Azure Event Hub throughput

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

In the service high-level description Microsoft mentions that I can stream millions of events per second and it is highly scalable

> Event Hubs is a fully managed, real-time data ingestion service that’s simple, trusted, and scalable. Stream **millions of events per second** from any source
> https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-hubs/

But when I go to the official documentation the maximum throughput units (TUs) limit is 20, which translates into 1000 event per TU * 20 TUs = 20,000 events:

> Event Hubs traffic is controlled by throughput units. A single throughput unit allows 1 MB per second or 1000 events per second of ingress and twice that amount of egress. Standard Event Hubs can be configured with 1-20 throughput units, and you can purchase more with a quota increase support request.
> https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-hubs/

How does 20TUs translate into streaming millions of events?

Comment: Per documentation, the 20-throughput-unit limit is a soft limit, and you can request additional throughput units (in batches of 20 TU). That's something you'd need to request, based on your specific subscription.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase 20-TUs by raising a support request.

But if you need to go very high you can also use Dedicated Clusters for Event Hubs.

Two important notes from the docs

> A Dedicated cluster guarantees capacity at full scale, and can ingress up to gigabytes of streaming data with fully durable storage and sub-second latency to accommodate any burst in traffic.

> At high ingress volumes (>100 TUs), a cluster costs significantly less per hour than purchasing a comparable quantity of throughput units in the Standard offering.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dedicated-overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dedicated-overview?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003556)

Answer (score 0):

The throughput capacity of Event Hubs is controlled by throughput units. Throughput units are pre-purchased units of capacity. A single throughput unit lets you: Ingress: Up to 1 MB per second or 1000 events per second (whichever comes first). Egress: Up to 2 MB per second or 4096 events per second.